# Unable to find file path in netbeans, java8

Tags: netbeans

I am new, I am trying to read text from a file in java, but I am unable to to that.
the program says:

```
private static Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("ARBITER_DICTIONARY.txt");
```

error:

`classes.jar could not start because a shared file path specified points to a file that does not exist. at myCode.GhostSkeleton.main(GhostSkeleton.java:25)`

I have tried to check the file path and name, everything seems to be correct

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution,

I the problems were of White spaces,

I removed all the white spaces, and it worked!

For example: "My File" will not work, but "MyFile" would work

Answer (score 1):

Or, try to remove add letters to white space, like add under score, it should definitely help.

underscore means: "_" don't get confused with dashes, "-"

Comment: Please use the edit option on your post instead of posting twice, unless this really is a completely separate answer. Your initial "Or" doesn't seem to indicate this.